# Identify a Pennsylvania weed with alternate lanceolate leaves

Tags: identification, weeds

Can anyone identify this weed? I am in western Pennsylvania and would appreciate knowing if it needs to be eradicated.

[image]

Comment: I don't recognize it, but once you have it identified: [You can get the list of plant species considered to be invasive in Pennsylvania here](http://www.dcnr.pa.gov/Conservation/WildPlants/InvasivePlants/Pages/default.aspx).

Comment: There is no such thing as eradicate or total control.  Just fyi.

Comment: It comes up as a wild bush with little purple flowers. I'm in Coatesville Pennsylvania, and have no idea what it's called. I keep them at the edge of the woods.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like some kind of native aster or woodland goldenrod.  It is not necessary to pull it.

Comment: oops, didn't see your comment down there.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is Polygonum persicaria; Smart Weed.  [smart weed](https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.NqU6xcaT5yXq4q2VLajw9gEsD8&pid=15.1&P=0&w=183&h=155)

Comment: Thanks, but I should have waited for it to flower and it became obvious: a native aster.